# How to antialias Plot3D graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, display, system-performance

How can I turn on antialiasing on 3D graphics from `Plot3D[]`?  2D graphics are antialiased for me but 3D graphics are very aliased and ugly looking, especially the coordinate axes.

I have seen people mentioning that your GPU must be powerful enough to enable antialiasing, but I have a very powerful GPU (Quadro M4000) and I can't even find the setting to enable it.

Comment: Can you check the Edit > Preferences menu item, and then look at the Appearance tab and the Graphics tab under it? You should see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJfWh.png).

Comment: @J.M. That worked, thanks!  Now I feel real dumb for not being able to find that.  If u add that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Antialiasing` option of `Style` only affects 2D graphics. For 3D plots the setting is global. To alter it, in the Mathematica Notebook menu choose *Edit*→*Preferences*, in dialog that appears go to *Appearance* tab, there to *Graphics* nested tab. Then move the slider to choose the amount of antialiasing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the antialiasing function to smooth your renderings. See the examples below:

[image]

Comment: This only works for 2D graphics, and has no effect on 3D plots.